# How to add Ruboto path to android sdk?

Tags: android, ruby, jruby, ubuntu-11.10, ruboto

I am new to Ruboto gem. I am currently working on android with Ruboto. I know android. I have installed the all requirements for Rubuto. I try to created the sample project using following command,

```
$ ruboto gen app --package org.sample.rubotoapp --target android-17

Output: Android SDK not in path
/bin/sh: android: not found
```

Please anybody can solve my problem. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Android SDK tools directory is not in your path.  If you check you path variable with

```
echo $PATH
```

it will probably not contain the Android SDK tools directory.  Also, you can check if the "android" command is in your path using

```
which android
```

You will probably get an empty response.

If you use Ruboto 0.12.0, you should be able to use

```
ruboto setup
```

to configure your environment.  Recently, in Android SDK r22, the path to the build tools was changed.  This will break your setup, and you will have to add

```
<android sdk location>/build-tools/17.0.0
```

to your path manually.  This is fixed for Ruboto 0.13.0 which will be released in june.